# group distinct rows and counting repeats

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

I am very new to SQL and I would like to create a sql function (or statement) that groups my transaction table based on `firstname` and `lastname`, while counting the number of repeats and the id.

`transaction` has the following columns: 
`id`, `firstname`,`lastname` etc..

I would like my return results look something like this in Json:

```
[{
    firstname:'John',
    lastname:'Doe',
    transaction_num:6,
    transaction_ids:[1,3,56,78,88,90]
},{
    firstname:'Jane',
    lastname:'Smith',
    transaction_num:2,
    transaction_ids:[8,9]
}]
```

Is there a way to do it in sql?

Comment: `SELECT firstname,lastname,GROUP_CONCAT(id) transaction_ids,COUNT(*) transaction_num FROM t GROUP BY firstname,lastname` Also transaction is a reserved name,you might want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT firstname,lastname,GROUP_CONCAT(id) transaction_ids,COUNT(*) transaction_num FROM t GROUP BY firstname,lastname`

As suggested by Mihai, perfect answer!